# Using Gmail's SMTP server to send 1000+ emails a day

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I have a web app that is currently sending roughly 1000 emails a day. I'm wondering if it's possible to switch to Gmail's SMTP server for this to hopefully iron out any issues with deliverability.

Do they allow for this amount of usage a day?

Comment: Having a look through their T&Cs is probably your best bet: https://mail.google.com/mail/help/intl/en/terms.html

Comment: This definitely sounds like an abuse of a *free* *personal* email service. If you need to send email in bulk, you can buy as many sends you need through their App Engine service at a reasonable rate.

Answer (score 3):

No.

[They have a much shorter limit.](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22839)

---

As a side note, do try [`postfix`](http://www.postfix.org/) if you're relying on `sendmail`. Should speed up things considerably.

Comment: I'm really looking for an outside service so I don't have to worry about white/blacklisting, etc. etc. etc. Checked out `sendgrid` but not sure if I want to cough up the $80/mo yet. Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: @Ian Silber I'm not the one saying this but... with the low RAM a postfix machine needs you can buy a linode, slicehost, whatever and use them as external mail servers for as low as $20/usd a month.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Frankie's answer, Gmail's sending limits are the following:

- 100 recipients at a time
- 500 recipients a day

More info: [Sending Limits — Gmail Help](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22839)